# Unable to resolve mapping file using Spring and JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

I'm trying to integrate Spring with JPA. I have defined one entity and added as mapping file under persistence.xml, but it throws the exception

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: MyPersistence] Unable to resolve named mapping-file [net.bb.spring.entities.DealDetailsEntity]
```

### My persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
     version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="MyPersistence">
<description>AS400 Configuration for BB</description>
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<mapping-file>net.bb.spring.entities.DealDetailsEntity</mapping-file>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:as400://172.21.100.101/BB" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="ROOT" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="ROOT" />
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
 </properties>

 </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From oracle docs about `persistence.xml` file:

> `<mapping-file>` element: specifies one or more object-relational
>   mapping XML files (orm.xml files).

What your `<mapping-file>` is pointing at is an `entity` which is a `java` `class`. This should not pass to `<mapping-file>` but to a `<class>` tag instead.

e.g.

```
<class>net.bb.spring.entities.DealDetailsEntity</class>
```